# How to generate a random string / password in Kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

For now, I deploy my application pods using static files and one of them is `app-secrets.yaml` with all secrets to deploy an application

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: app-secrets
type: Opaque
data:
  root: xxxxxx
  user1: xxxxxx
  user2: xxxxxx
```

but this is not neither secure nor convenient (if I need another app instance, I have to create another file with human-generated password).

I'm looking to generate random passwords at application creation but I don't know if it's possible.
I've already looked to the topic [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) and especially `secretGenerator` but this is not directly what I want as I understand it, because it does not create a random string but a random secret name like `secret/app-secrets-ssdsdfmfh4k` but I have to provide still the passwords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use [kubernetes-secret-generator](https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-secret-generator). I've tested it and it's doing exactly what you need.

To accomplish it you have to have helm in your cluster and follow these instructions:

Clone repository

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-secret-generator
```

Create helm deployment

```
$ helm upgrade --install secret-generator ./deploy/chart
```

Now you to use it, you just have to

> Add annotation `secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/autogenerate` to any
> Kubernetes secret object .The value of the annotation can be a field
> name (or comma separated list of field names) within the secret; the
> SecretGeneratorController will pick up this annotation and add a field
> [or fields] (`password` in the example below) to the secret with a
> randomly generated string value. From [here](https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-secret-generator#usage).

```
$ kubectl apply -f mysecret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  annotations:
    secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/autogenerate: password
data:
  username: UGxlYXNlQWNjZXB0Cg==
```

After applying this secret you can take a look at it to check if the passward was generated as expected:

```
$ kubectl get secrets mysecret -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: dnVKTDBJZ0tFS1BacmtTMnBuc3d2YWs2YlZsZ0xPTUFKdStDa3dwUQ==
  username: UGxlYXNlQWNjZXB0Cg==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"username":"UGxlYXNlQWNjZXB0Cg=="},"kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{"secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/autogenerate":"password"},"name":"mysecret","namespace":"default"}}
    secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/autogenerate: password
    secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/autogenerate-generated-at: 2020-01-09 14:29:44.397648062
      +0000 UTC m=+664.011602557
    secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/secure: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-09T14:29:44Z"
  name: mysecret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "297425"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/mysecret
  uid: 7ae42d71-32ec-11ea-92b3-42010a800009
type: Opaque
```

As we can see, the password was generated.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, unfortunate that k8s does not provide that by default and that this project uses helm for deployment.

Comment: Passwords are not encrypted ! they are only encoded. 
Everyone can read the password you posted. I want to make sure there is no misconception about base64 encoding vs encryption, as it could give a false sense of security.

The secret you posted contains:
    username: PleaseAccept
    password: vuJL0IgKEKPZrkS2pnswvak6bVlgLOMAJu+CkwpQ

Answer (score 4):

You can do this too:

```
$ head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 8 ; echo '' | base64 | kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=password=-
```

The inconvenient is that you need to change secret name every time you run the command, but looks like you already have a mechanism to generate random secret names.

Note: change the number in `head -c 8` to control the length of the string.

Comment: The example above doesn't work, so I give the working one:

`head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 8 | xargs -I {} kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=password={}`

Comment: @red First of all, I just tried with k8s 1.20, and it DID work. and you should expect some posts to get outdated after a year and half.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back @suren's answer this is how it should be done today

If you want to dry run,

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 8 | kubectl create secret generic xxx --dry-run=client --from-file=password=/dev/stdin -o json
```

To create the secret and decode,

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 8 | kubectl create secret generic xxx --from-file=password=/dev/stdin

kubectl get secret xxx -o jsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how we do it my team:

```
{{ randAlphaNum 30 | b64enc | quote }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes natively does not have this functionality.

If you want to perform this yourself manually check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496647/automatically-generated-strings-for-secrets-using-yaml-config)

If you want to automate this manual task then you can use this custom [controller](https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-secret-generator) to perform this.

Add the annotation secret-generator.v1.mittwald.de/autogenerate to any Kubernetes secret object. The value of the annotation can be a field name (or comma separated list of field names) within the secret; the SecretGeneratorController will pick up this annotation and add a field [or fields] (password in the example below) to the secret with a randomly generated string value